# if the ```.pyc``` file only consists of the imported module's bytecode, how does the other code in the main file (.py) gets executed?

Tags: python, import, bytecode, pyc

(I don't know whether I am stating this correctly. If you find any mistake, correct me.)

If the `.pyc` file only consists of the imported module's bytecode, how does the other code in the main file (.py) gets executed?

```
import foo
print('Hello World')
```

To the best of my knowledge, in the above code, `.pyc` file will only contain the bytecode of `foo.py`. So is the bytecode for the `print` function executed in memory and it vanishes after the work is done?

2. I read somewhere that Python program can be executed without the source file or the main file if we have the `.pyc` file. If we consider the above code and assume that the source file is not present with us but the .pyc file is present. How would the bytecode of the `print` function be generated as the `.pyc` file only consists of the bytecode of `foo.py`?

Comment: What is this "main" file that you speak of..?

Comment: @thebjorn .py file

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://www.quora.com/How-does-Python-execute-code